# xcode 4.3.2 codeSense problems

Tags: xcode4.3, codesense

I just updated to 4.3.2 and now I'm am having codeSense sleeping on me at every turn.
During coding I'm getting partial listings from enums, partial or no properties for classes, often no syntax highlighting, no errors for undeclared variables.

If I build the project it raises the right warning/errors and links everything right.
So it actually can figure out if something is wrong, it just does not seem make an effort to do it while I'm writing code.

So angry right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue recently and I wound up Deleting the Derived Data for the project and the restarting Xcode.

In Xcode go into the Organizer and under the Projects tab select your project from the left and then press delete next to Derived Data.  Then restart xcode and hopefully you'll be good to go.

Comment: I deleted the derived data and restarted which seems to have fixed things (for now).

Comment: While deleting derived data works every time, those of us that have this problem chronically (my project = once every 15 minutes), clearly we need another solution :(

Comment: I've had more xcode crashes with this new version than the previous one. Also I miss how it no longer points out the reasons for an "incomplete implementation" like the previous version did.
I've noticed code sense seems to stop working after I rename source files, but this is not always a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got that problem when using some c++ files on my iOS project...
very anoying

you can fix it easily like this:

on your project, go to "build settings"

"Build Options"

"Compiler for c/c++/objective-c""
change it from Apple `LLVM compiler 3.1`

to

`LLVM GCC 4.2`  Build

and change it back again to

> LLVM compiler 3.1

Build again

now codeSense should work!

PS. no need to delete derived data...

;)

Comment: I tried these steps, but it was still messing up for me after.
It probably needed a restart among other things. I don't mind deleting the derived data if it fixes the problems.
is there any benefit to using the LLVM GCC 4.2?